# Standard APIs to access the front camera on different platforms

Tags: api, mobile, camera

On the following platforms:

- iOS
- Android
- Symbian
- J2ME (with MMAPI)
- Windows Mobile (Windows Phone7).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these platforms have any API in common (even J2ME vs Android), therefore there is no standard for the camera.

Comment: I mean individual API, not in common.